# Abîme des cieux/Autre abîme signification Poésie Victor Hugo

Tags: sens, poésie

Que signifie « abîme des cieux » et « autre abîme ? »

« Abîme des cieux » semble désigner le ciel mais comment peut-on se pencher sur quelque chose qui se trouve en hauteur ?

Le poème :

> Un jour…
>
> Un jour je vis, debout au bord des flots mouvants,
> Passer, gonflant ses voiles,
> Un rapide navire enveloppé de vents,
> De vagues et d’étoiles ;
>
> **Et j’entendis, penché sur l’abîme des cieux,
>
> Que l’autre abîme touche,**
> Me parler à l’oreille une voix dont mes yeux
> Ne voyaient pas la bouche :
>
> « Poëte, tu fais bien ! Poëte au triste front,
> Tu rêves près des ondes,
> Et tu tires des mers bien des choses qui sont
> Sous les vagues profondes !
>
> La mer, c’est le Seigneur, que, misère ou bonheur,
> Tout destin montre et nomme ;
> Le vent, c’est le Seigneur ; l’astre, c’est le Seigneur ;
> Le navire, c’est l’homme. »

Comment: *Se pencher* (symboliquement), c’est porter une attention aiguë et subtile sur un sujet de profonde réflexion, se fondre dans l’objet étudié, cela n’a rien à voir avec une inclinaison quelconque par rapport à la verticalité.

Comment: Merci.Et à propos de l’abîme des cieux et de l'autre abîme, qu'est-ce que ça signifie s'il vous plait ?

Comment: *Abîme* : gouffre dont la profondeur est insondable. Du temps de V. Hugo, on ne connaissait pas le fond des océans ; que ce soit en dessous de la surface où voguent les marins, ou en miroir au-dessus de leur tète, les connaissances étaient limitées, entraînant des interrogations ou des frayeurs incommensurables.

Comment: C'est pour l'explication de texte ?

Answer (score 1):

En lisant la première strophe, et comme signalé dans [le commentaire de Personne](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41946/ab%C3%AEme-des-cieux-autre-ab%C3%AEme-signification-po%C3%A9sie-victor-hugo#comment85380_41946), **l'autre abîme semble faire référence aux fonds marins**. Cette interprétation fait sens puisqu'en mer, à l'horizon, il est parfois difficile de distinguer le ciel de l'eau.

Comment: En effet, merci.